# whenever i click on any link in sidebar(i.e about, work, contact, etc) that particular Component should open inside Content component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

new to React Router, my question is how to render a particular component inside other layout which is already rendered (i have two components sidebar and content i just want if i click on any link in sidebar that component will we render in already render Content component not override that)

```
////////////Sidebar.js////////////

import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import PersonalImg from '../images/personal.gif'

const Sidebar = () => {
   return (
       <div className="sidebar">
           <BrowserRouter>
               <div className="personal-img">
                   <img src={PersonalImg} alt="personl-img" />
               </div>
               <div className="navigation">
                   <ul className="list">
                       <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                       <li><Link to="/work">Work</Link></li>
                       <li><Link to="/skills">Skills</Link></li>
                       <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
           </BrowserRouter>
       </div>
   )
}

export default Sidebar;


Content component...
/////////////////Content.js//////////////////

import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import About from './About'
import Skills from './Skills'
import Work from './Work'
import Contact from './Contact'

const Content = (props) => {

   return (
       <div className="content">
           <BrowserRouter>
               <Route path="/" componet={About} />             
               <Route path="/work" componet={Work} />             
               <Route path="/contact" componet={Contact} />             
               <Route path="/skills" componet={Skills} />             
           </BrowserRouter>
       </div>
   )
}

export default Content;

and thats how App.js rendering these components

render() {
   return (
     <Fragment>
         <Sidebar />
         <Content />
     </Fragment>
   )
 }
```

Comment: In that case, you don't need routing at all. You can render all the components on single page and maintain state to show hide on click of link/button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I have created small demo for you
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-glade-vnj0l

Problem 1: `componet` spell is wrong. It should be *`component`* in the `Route`.

Problem 2: set `exact` keyword for the first route like this `<Route exact path="/" componet={About} />`.

Use single `BrowserRouter` throughout the application.

Comment: OP not asked to fix the code, he don't need to override the component but display one after one as he clicks the link without replacing exsisting component.

Comment: He want to render selected component inside the Content component only. He don't want everything in one component.

Comment: read this - *(i have two components sidebar and content i just want if i click on any link in sidebar that component will we render in already render Content component not override that)*

Comment: Let's wait for him reply. If he want something like this then we will update it.

Comment: thanks @ClueMediator for this help it works i just fixed those mistakes that you have pointed out. this was my first stack overflow question and you saved lot of my time...thanks